# How can I escape special characters in Terraform script?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using the aws provider and trying to generate a password without special characters. But I'm not sure how I can list them all thats acceptable in HCL. I have tried adding $${} or %%{} with no joy as I found in the documentation. A sample below:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_random_password" "password" {
  password_length     = 25
  exclude_punctuation = %%{# $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ! " ~ .}
}
```

I get:

This character is not used within the language.
Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exclude_punctuation` expects a boolean:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_random_password" "password" {
  password_length     = 25
  exclude_punctuation = true
}
```

and if you also want to exclude other characters, use `exclude_characters`, which should be a string:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_random_password" "password" {
  password_length     = 25
  exclude_punctuation = true
  exclude_characters  = "xyz"
}
```